# Can't connect to source server

Tags: hosting, garrys-mod, source-engine

Today I set up a little GMOD server. I wasn't able to access it from the public ip, only through the network ip of the server. I wasn't able to ping the server using the public ip. Now, when using the ipv6 format I can ping the server, but I can't play on it. The console says: "Bad server address". How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't port forwarded. Go [here](http://portforward.com/english/applications/port_forwarding/Garrys_Mod/default.htm) then select your router and it will tell you how to port forward.

Comment: I did.  But it just wont work

Comment: go to http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ to make sure your ports are actually open.  just enter one port like 27015 (I haven't done gmod in a while so i cant remember actual ports needed for gmod).  let me know if it is open or not.

Comment: ok. its not. my router says its open.